# How to change the size of an Android View by dragging its edges or corners?

Tags: android

I want to let the user change the size of a View by first choosing control over it (with a long touch) and then dragging one of the corners (or edges) and resize it accordingly.

I've got the control part covered, but I would like to know if there is something which allows me to make this resize besides having to create this mechanics from scratch. I should add that my views already translate when an user drags them, by overriding the onLongClick method.

Something like the "cut" function in most apps right now, only that resizes. Here's an example where the edges are "draggable":

[image: Example of the resize mechanics]

Answer (score 3):

What i get from the image you need to build a cropper. The Frame you draw overlay is view So just override onTouch() of View and invalidate the view with new points and size.

```
 @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // check for the point
            // 1.if its exist inside the frame then move the frame on action move
            // 2. if its on edges then reassign the size of frame and invalidate your View
            // 3. if Outside the frame just ignore it
            onDown(event);
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            // Move your view here i.e assign new points and size as per event 
            invalidate();
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:

            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: So what I should do is build a class "Overlay" or something like that, and create an Overlay on top of the View when I touch on the edges?

EDIT: Forget what I said above. I got what you were saying, the problem is my Views also move. So, I can't have the "move" listener on the View itself. I think I'll create "Points" and assign that listener to them and put each point on a corner.

Comment: Instead of that i suggest you use a third party cropper library. Because these are already optimized and works without lacking. You can then understand code and can build your own . There are lots of available on github already build by amazing coders and some are of only a Single .Java file and works like a Charm .